# Multi match query with AND condition in elastic search php

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I want to search on multiple field with AND condition. I have tried many ways but I am not able to generate result.

below is my code.

```
   "query" =>[
                    "multi_match" => [
                    "fields" => ["prod_name", "prod_seo_name"],
                    "type" => "phrase_prefix",
                    "query" => $query
                    ],
                     "bool" => [
                        "must" => [
                        "term" => [ "cat_type_id" => 1 ],

                     ],
                ],
            ],
```

I want to search with *product name* whose *cat_type_id* is *1*.

I have tried following too.

```
"query" =>[
                            "multi_match" => [
                            "fields" => ["prod_name", "prod_seo_name"],
                            "type" => "phrase_prefix",
                            "query" => $query
                    ],
                     "filter" => [
                        "term"=> ["cat_type_id"=>1]
                    ]
```

Any help or reference would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to do it is like this:

```
"query" => [
   "bool" => [
      "must" => [
         [
              "multi_match" => [
                  "fields" => ["prod_name", "prod_seo_name"],
                  "type" => "phrase_prefix",
                  "query" => $query
              ]
         ],
         [
              "term"=> ["cat_type_id"=>1]
         ]
      ]
   ]
]
```

Comment: Can I add multiple terms in this . like AND operator? and If I want to pass extra filters how could I achieve? Any reference plz

Comment: Of course you can. A good starting point would be the reference documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html